# Non-rectangular footers in Latex with page text flowing around logo

Tags: floats, header-footer, fancyhdr

How can I generate a page footer on every page of a document that is not rectangular, i.e. that has a larger logo with the page text flowing around it?

I'm trying to replicate a page layout conforming to our Corporate Identity / Design, which has a small footer and a larger logo in the lower right corner. The body text is supposed to flow around the logo. How can I do this in LaTeX. My current attempts using fancyhdr always result in a rectangular footer with the height of the logo, thus leaving a lot of space unfilled.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\lfoot{\fbox{\parbox[b][0.5cm]{0.3\textwidth}{Normal Footer...}}}
\rfoot{\fbox{\parbox[b][3cm]{0.3\textwidth}{\raggedright Larger logo coming here, page text should flow around it...}}} % larger footer

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```

I'm trying to get a page layout like the following:[image]

I have also tried using an overlay on every page for the logo, but that clearly makes the text not flow around the logo. In a similar vein, I have tried to make the box extentions of the logo smaller so that that the body text goes until the textual lfoot. Again, this clearly does not allow the body text to wrap around the logo.

Comment: short answer is that tex doesn't support this. longer answer is you can usually do something depending on how easy it is to control page breaking manually in your situation.