# Wrap text around picture in fancyhdr header

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, wrapfigure, includegraphics, header

I would like to be able to wrap the text around the logo in the fancyhdr reader on all other pages than the first.

As you can see on the screenshot there is text over the logo. I do not want to increase the height of the header, i would like the text to wrap.

[image: Text over logo in header]

The code:

Main.tex

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{report}
\input{packages} % Include packeges
\input{Preamble} % Include custom commands
\newcounter{sprog}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Set language for appendix
\setcounter{sprog}{1} % 1 for danish, 2 for english

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Definere info about yourself
\newcommand{\name}{}
\newcommand{\studyline}{}
\newcommand{\semester}{}
\newcommand{\appendixnumber}{FRxxx-xx} % remmember to add -English for english appendix
\newcommand{\definetitle}{
    \Sprog{Opstilling til XXX}{Candidacy for XXX}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Beginning of document

\begin{document}

% Title and info
\createtitle 
\vspace{-1cm}

% Nice picture of yourself
\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{0.4\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{images/Picture1.png}
    \caption{xxxx}
    \vspace{-1cm}
\end{wrapfigure}\leavevmode

% Body text
\section*{English summary}

\blindtext

\section*{Motivation}
\Blindtext

\Blindtext

\Blindtext

\subsection*{Kompetencer}
\Blindtext

\Blindtext

\Blindtext

\subsection*{Sub-title}


\Blindtext




\end{document}
```

packages.tex:

```
% ALLE PAKKER TIL BRUG I DAGSORDENEN
\usepackage[danish]{babel} % danske overskrifter
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Skal passe til editorens indstillinger
\usepackage[sfdefault]{roboto}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % fonte (output)
\usepackage{lmodern} % vektor fonte
\usepackage{graphicx} % indsættelse af billeder
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
```

Preamble.tex

```
\usepackage{xstring}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Commandoer brugt til opsætning

\newcommand{\Sprog}[2]{\ifnum\value{sprog} = 1 #1\else #2\fi}

\definecolor{PFBlue}{cmyk}{100,0,0,0}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Page layout
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.7em}
\sectionfont{\color{PFBlue}} 
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{1em}{-0.75em}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{0em}{-0.75em}

\textwidth = 470pt
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-2cm}
%\marginparwidth = 86pt
\hoffset = -25pt
\voffset= -15pt
\textheight = 23cm  %23cm
\headheight = 156pt
\headsep = -65pt    %-65pt
\footskip = 50pt
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{blindtext}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Opstilling med billede
\newcommand{\createtitle}{
    \Huge \definetitle \normalsize \\
    \textcolor{PFBlue}{\rule{13.5cm}{2pt}} 

    \textbf{\Sprog{Navn:}{Name:} \name} \\
    \textbf{\Sprog{Studieretning:}{Study Line:}} \studyline \\
    \textbf{Semester: \semester}
}



\renewcommand\labelenumi{\bfseries\theenumi}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Header og footer
\fancyhf{} % tom header/footer

%\Sprog{Bilagsnummer: }{Appendix: } \appendixnumber
\fancyhfoffset{71pt}
\fancyhead[L]{
    \hspace{71pt} 
    \vspace{100pt} 
    \Sprog{Bilagsnr.:}{Appendix:} \appendixnumber 
} 

\fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[width=5.25cm]{images/logo_rgb.png}}
\fancyhead[CE]{}
\fancyfoot[FC]{\Sprog{Side}{Page} \thepage{} \Sprog{af}{of} \pageref*{LastPage}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\makeindex 

%\setlength\parindent{0pt}
```

I'm sorry i'm not able to provide a simpler example. I hope you'll be able to help.

I've tried to finde similar issues but I've been unable to apply them to my problem.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: You want the text of the main body to wrap around the header (which overlays text area).  Sorry, not possible.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/483180/non-rectangular-footers-in-latex-with-page-text-flowing-around-logo.  You could use flowfram to create pages with odd shapes, but TeX will not automatically change the width of a paragraph which spans two frames.