Placing a figure at the bottom left of the page and wrapping the text around it properly
I need to place a figure at the bottom-left of the page and wrap the text around it. The text comes via \input, hence I do not have direct control on where to put the \wrapfig environment within the text.
This process will be done for hundred pages, so I need a way to achieve this without editing into \input text. Each \input text is ensured to not exceed a single page.
What I want to achieve is:

As an example, this code:
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\lipsum[1-4]
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.7\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=0.99\linewidth]{example-image}
\end{wrapfigure}

\end{document}

pushes the figure out of the lower border and the text is not wrapped properly:

Any suggestions?

I have a feeling that doing this automatically is difficult, given how TeX works with paragraphs and pages. (But I would love to be proven wrong.)

Unfortunately, these two questions and answers state there is no solution possible in TeX fo create a page layout you need: [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/515827/wrap-text-around-picture-in-fancyhdr-header] and [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/483180/non-rectangular-footers-in-latex-with-page-text-flowing-around-logo].

Is it always the same image?  And more importantly, do you know the dimensions for the image(s)?

What you have should work. You just need to adjust the image and add more text after the image.
Take a look at this:

And here is the code:
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\lipsum[1-3]
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.6\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=0.88\linewidth]{example-image}
\end{wrapfigure}

\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}


I don't think this answers the question, the OP wants the cutout at the bottom of the page without inserting the wrapfig within the text sources which come from an external \input your image shows teh insert a line above the bottom, and you have the wrapfig between the  lipsum paragraphs

The OP should move the text he/she wants by the figure after the figure env in LaTeX. Why would Latex do it by default?

This is a typical "magazine layout" where the requirement is for the figure to be in a cutout at the bottom of the page and the text content flow round it.  In your example, to make the figure come at the requested position you would have to change the markup for the text  replacing \lipsum by expanded text and move the wrapfig later so it came  lower. The OP wants to avoid that such edits. So at the very least, to answer the question, you should show how to move the wrapfig down two lines have two full width lines in the final paragraph and then the wrapfig runs to the bottom of the page.

Although I commented that this magazine type of layout would be impossible in LaTex, I have been trying to work out a possible solution. I have come this far:
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[absolute,showboxes,]{textpos}
    \setlength{\TPHorizModule}{25mm}
    \setlength{\TPVertModule}{\TPHorizModule}
    \textblockorigin{25mm}{25mm} % start everything at the top-left corner
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\usepackage[body={16.0cm,24.8cm},top=2.5cm,left=2.5cm,showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{changepage}

\usepackage{lineno}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    
    \TPShowGrid*{7}{10}
    
    \begin{textblock}{4.3}(0,6.8)
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
            \includegraphics[width=0.99\linewidth]{example-image}
    \end{textblock}
    
    \begin{linenumbers}
%       \modulolinenumbers[51]

    \section*{Some textual filling}
    
    \lipsum[1-4]
    
    \lipsum[5][1-5]
    
    \begin{adjustwidth}{112mm}{0mm}
        \lipsum[5][6-]
    \end{adjustwidth}

    \end{linenumbers}

\end{document}

Which results in this layout with all boxes and linenumbers shown:

The lineno package is able to number the lines in a text. As can be seen from line number 35 onwards the margin of the text should be adjusted to accomodate for the position of the figure. That line number can be retrieved by \thelinenumber making it possible to create an if-then-else macro using the ifthen-package and possible some others.
Unfortunately, that is beyond my LaTeX knowledge, and I would like to see if someone can extend on this idea.
The final step would be to create a page template from this option.

I modified my solution from here to also do page bottoms.  The main difference is that the paragraph after wrappage does not have to be the last paragraph on the page, but the figure must start in the next paragraph.
Placing wrappage too early or too late can have odd effects.  As a rule, only use wrappage after trying wrapfigure in the same location.
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{afterpage}

\makeatletter
\newsavebox{\wp@image}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{wrappage}{O{0} m O{0} m}{\par
% #1 (optional) is the number of lines until the end of the page
% #2 is r (right) or l (left)
% #3 (optional) is the number of lines for the image.
% #4 width (or 0pt to compute).
  \xdef\wp@page{#1}%
  \ifnum\wp@page=0\relax
    \dimen0=\dimexpr \pagegoal-\pagetotal\relax
    \xdef\wp@page{\the\numexpr \dimen0/\baselineskip}%
  \fi
  \xdef\wp@side{#2}%
  \xdef\wp@lines{#3}%
  \xdef\wp@width{#4}%
  \def\@captype{figure}%
  \wp@environ}% body here
{\endwp@environ
  \ifnum\wp@lines=0\relax
    \dimen0=\dimexpr \ht\wp@image+\dp\wp@image+\intextsep\relax
    \xdef\wp@lines{\the\numexpr \dimen0/\baselineskip}%
  \fi
  \ifdim \wp@page\baselineskip>\dimexpr\wp@lines\baselineskip+\intextsep\relax% put image on this page
    \if r\wp@side\relax
      \wp@right@here% put image on right side
    \else
      \if l\wp@side\relax
        \wp@left@here% put image on left side
      \else
        \errmessage{Bad wrappage argument: \textbf{\wp@side} must be \texbf{r} or \textbf{l}.}%
      \fi
    \fi
  \else
    \if r\wp@side\relax
      \wp@right% put image on right side
    \else
      \if l\wp@side\relax
        \wp@left% put image on left side
      \else
        \errmessage{Bad wrappage argument: \textbf{\wp@side} must be \texbf{r} or \textbf{l}.}%
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
\ignorespaces}

\NewEnviron{wp@environ}{% put \BODY into \wp@image
  \ifdim\wp@width=0pt
    \savebox\wp@image{\varwidth{\textwidth}
      \renewcommand{\caption}[2][\empty]{\par}% dummy caption
      \BODY
    \endvarwidth}%
    \xdef\wp@width{\the\wd\wp@image}%
  \fi
  \global\setbox\wp@image=\hbox{\parbox{\wp@width}{\BODY}}%
}

\def\wp@right@here{% handle right side wrapfig for this page
  \noindent\hspace{\dimexpr \textwidth-\wp@width}%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr \ht\strutbox+\dp\wp@image-\pagegoal+\pagetotal}[0pt][0pt]%
    {\usebox\wp@image}%
  \vspace{\dimexpr -\baselineskip-\parskip}\par
  \wp@make@parshape{\numexpr \wp@page-\wp@lines}{\wp@lines}%
    {0pt}{\textwidth-\wp@width-\columnsep}%
  \AddToHookNext{para/before}{\parshape=\wp@parshape}%
  \AddToHookNext{para/after}{\dimen1=\dimexpr \pagegoal-\pagetotal\relax%
    \ifdim\dimen1>0pt\relax% not done yet
      \ifdim\dimen1>3\baselineskip\relax% avoid forced pagebreak
        \leavevmode\vspace{-\baselineskip}%
        \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{\wp@width}
          \vskip-\intextsep
          \rule{0pt}{\dimen1}
          \vskip-\intextsep
        \end{wrapfigure}\vskip-\baselineskip\indent
      \else
        \hangindent=-\dimexpr \wp@width+\columnsep\relax
        \hangafter=-\numexpr \dimen1/\baselineskip\relax
      \fi
    \fi}%
}

\def\wp@left@here{% handle left side wrapfig for this page
  \noindent\raisebox{\dimexpr \ht\strutbox+\dp\wp@image-\pagegoal+\pagetotal}[0pt][0pt]%
    {\usebox\wp@image}%
  \vspace{\dimexpr -\baselineskip-\parskip}\par
  \wp@make@parshape{\numexpr \wp@page-\wp@lines}{\wp@lines}%
    {\wp@width+\columnsep}{\textwidth-\wp@width-\columnsep}%
  \AddToHookNext{para/before}{\parshape=\wp@parshape}%
  \AddToHookNext{para/after}{\dimen1=\dimexpr \pagegoal-\pagetotal\relax%
    \ifdim\dimen1>0pt\relax% not done yet
      \ifdim\dimen1>3\baselineskip\relax% avoid forced pagebreak
        \leavevmode\vspace{-\baselineskip}%
        \begin{wrapfigure}{l}{\wp@width}
          \vskip-\intextsep
          \rule{0pt}{\dimen1}
          \vskip-\intextsep
        \end{wrapfigure}\vskip-\baselineskip\indent
      \else
        \hangindent=\dimexpr \wp@width+\columnsep\relax
        \hangafter=-\numexpr \dimen1/\baselineskip\relax
      \fi
    \fi}%
}
   
\def\wp@right{% handle right side wrapfig
  \afterpage{\xdef\wp@extra{\the\dimexpr \wp@lines\baselineskip-\ht\AP@partial-\dp\AP@partial}%
    \rlap{\hspace{\dimexpr \textwidth-\wp@width}% stay in v;mode
    \raisebox{\dimexpr \topskip-\height}[0pt][0pt]{\box\wp@image}}%
    \vskip-\baselineskip
    \unvbox\AP@partial
    \AddToHookNext{para/after}{\leavevmode\vspace{-\baselineskip}%
    \ifdim\wp@extra>0pt\relax
      \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{\wp@width}
        \vskip-\intextsep
        \rule{0pt}{\wp@extra}
        \vskip-\intextsep
      \end{wrapfigure}\vskip-\baselineskip\indent
    \fi}}%
  \wp@make@parshape{\wp@page}{\wp@lines}%
    {0pt}{\textwidth-\wp@width-\columnsep}%
  \AddToHookNext{para/before}{\parshape=\wp@parshape}
}

\def\wp@left{% handle left side wrapfig
  \afterpage{\xdef\wp@extra{\the\dimexpr \wp@lines\baselineskip-\ht\AP@partial-\dp\AP@partial}%
    \noindent\raisebox{\dimexpr \topskip-\height}[0pt][0pt]{\box\wp@image}% stay in vmode
    \vskip-\baselineskip
    \unvbox\AP@partial
    \AddToHookNext{para/after}{\leavevmode\vspace{-\baselineskip}%
    \ifdim\wp@extra>0pt\relax
      \begin{wrapfigure}{l}{\wp@width}
        \vskip-\intextsep
        \rule{0pt}{\wp@extra}
        \vskip-\intextsep
      \end{wrapfigure}\vskip-\baselineskip\indent
    \fi}}%
  \wp@make@parshape{\wp@page}{\wp@lines}%
    {\wp@width+\columnsep}{\textwidth-\wp@width-\columnsep}%
  \AddToHookNext{para/before}{\parshape=\wp@parshape}
}

\newcommand{\wp@make@parshape}[4]{%
% #1 = number lines delay
% #2 = number lines wrapped
% #3 = left side wrapped
% #4 = right side wrapped
  \xdef\wp@parshape{\the\numexpr #1+#2+1}%
  \edef\wp@length{\the\textwidth}%
  \count1=#1\relax
  \loop\ifnum \count1>0
    \advance\count1 by -1
    \xdef\wp@parshape{\wp@parshape\space 0pt \wp@length}% delay
  \repeat
  \edef\wp@indent{\the\dimexpr #3}%
  \edef\wp@length{\the\dimexpr #4}%
  \count1=#2\relax
  \loop\ifnum \count1>0
    \advance\count1 by -1
    \xdef\wp@parshape{\wp@parshape\space \wp@indent\space \wp@length}% wrap
  \repeat
  \xdef\wp@parshape{\wp@parshape\space 0pt \the\textwidth}% back to normal
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\noindent
\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{wrappage}{l}{0.5\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\end{wrappage}

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}


While using \hangindent is much simpler, it only works if the figure extends across two paragraphs.  If it fits inside one paragraph, you need \parshape.

I think having \lipsum[4-8] after the image doesn't fit OP's requirements.

But it did make it easier to debug.
